# Install program on external HDD with Mac Book Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-space, hdd

I'new in the Machintosh world. I'am running out of space on my Mac, so i try to install Epic Games and Fortnite on external HDD.
Is it possible? How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you get the games.  Steam can be told to use several locations and move games between them,